# Latest call in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

In my C++ library I need to call a C library. The C library has two functions: `start()` and `stop()`. In my application I created a singleton like that:

```
class MySingleton {
private:
    MySingleton() { start(); }
    ~MySingleton() { stop(); }
    //other attributes here, singleton keeps a "state"
public:
    static MySingleton& getInstance() {
        static MySingleton m;
        return m;
    }
};
```

In other classes dynamically allocated and "tracked" via `shared_ptr` I call the C library in destructors:

```
class Foo {
public:
    ~Foo() { //call c library }
};
```

The problem: I have no control over the destruction of the singleton using a static method. At application exit it could happen that singleton destructor is called before another destructor calling the C library after `stop()`. What's the best way to avoid that? Ideally I should say "call the destructor of the singleton as latest call", is it possible?

Comment: Should `start()` and `stop()` be called only once? Then why not  create your class as a normal non-singleton class, and create an instance of it first thing in the `main` function? And if you're worried that someone might create an instance of the class somewhere else, then [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) with the [`std::once_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) as a static member?

Comment: And remember [the single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), don't let your classes handle too much responsibility.

Comment: It's a C++ library, I have no "main" where to instantiate this class.

Comment: Surely static instances are destructed after `main()` exits?

Comment: @greywolf82 the first time `MySingleton::getInstance()` will be called the instance will be created. The fact the moment the instance is deleted compared to some other classes instances when exit is relevant indicates a problem in your architecture

Comment: It seems obvious there's a problem, it's the reason why I asked. At exit the exit handlers can be executed and the same time static objects can be deallocated.

Comment: Then you really can't protect yourself against the static initialization fiasco. Instead create two API functions, one that must be called before anything else, and one that must be called last thing:. Then ***document*** those functions, and stress when and where they must be called. If the user of your library doesn't do that, it's their own fault if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, it seems the only thing I can do. I just wanted to see if there was something better.

Comment: If you're "tracking" something using a `shared_ptr`, then the only occasion when that `shared_ptr` may be destructed (and then call the C library) after destruction of your singleton is if that `shared_ptr` is also a static.    The simple solution - make the `shared_ptr` have automatic storage duration (e.g. by defining it in `main()`) so it is always destroyed before the singleton.     The more general solution is to avoid statics, as that makes it easier to control lifetime (and therefore order of construction/destruction) using objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: Can you make use of the [nifty counter idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) to control construction/destruction?

Comment: @G.M. It could be an alternative to be evaluated, thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in knowing the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html)

Comment: I know very well the rule of five, code snippet is just to provide an idea of the problem

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to employ singleton pattern in your application, you can take something from Andrei Alexandrescu's book "Modern C++ Design". There is a chapter dedicated to singleton implementation. In particular he addresses the problem of destruction order in paragraph "6.8 Implementing Singletons with Longevity". He provides an implementation with deterministic destruction order.

But personally, I wouldn't employ singleton pattern. You create so much problems to solve just to guarantee the single instance of an object. If you quit this approach, things might get so much simpler (there are many ways to solve the problem depending on your program's architecture). Yes, someone can create a second instance, but it is your program, you have access to its' source, so you can ensure no one does it.